# Get shape of my bodies using Box2D

Tags: java, box2d

I would like to get the shapes of my bodies, but I can't get anything, only null. Why?
Here is the relevant code section:

```
Body b;
while((b = box2d.physics.PhysicsWorld.world.getBodyList().getNext()) !=null) {
  Shape shape;
  while((shape = b.getShapeList().getNext()) != null) {

    Log.e("name",""+b.getUserData().toString()+" "+shape+" ");

    opengl.saveMatrix();
    Meshes.select(b.getUserData().toString())
              .translate((b.getPosition().x)*RATIO, (b.getPosition().y)*RATIO)
              .rotate((int) ((int) b.getAngle() * (180 / Math.PI)), 0, 0, 1)
              .draw(shape, 1, 1, 1);

    opengl.loadMatrix();

  }
}
```

`shape = b.getShapeList().getNext()` always returns null, and the log entry never ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing by the presence of `Log.e` and `toString()` that this is Java on Android. I don't know much about JBox2D in Java, but...

```
while((b = box2d.physics.PhysicsWorld.world.getBodyList().getNext()) !=null)
```

You're only ever going to get the second body here. I can't imagine this loop would ever terminate if it was entered. Your other loop has a similar problem:

```
while((shape = b.getShapeList().getNext()) != null)
```

In Box2D, shapes and bodies form a linked list. getBodyList and getShapeList return the head of that linked list, which is itself a body/shape, not an iterator. (Your loop is wrong even if it was an iterator, though! If something returns an iterator, you need to keep using the one it returned, not ask for it again.)

The loop you want is of the form:

```
for (Body b = box2d.physics.PhysicsWorld.world.getBodyList();
     b != null;
     b = b.getNext())
```